# how to print numberlong value?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

So, I tried to print a NumberLong to console from a mongoshell.
However, when I casted the NumberLong variable into string, the value got rounded down. After initial search, it looks like it happens because the precision limit of javascript float.
Here is one example in mongoshell:

```
var abc = NumberLong(2517720935641120769);
print(abc);
```

The output is

```
NumberLong("2517720935641120769")
```

However, when I tried to cast it into string to just print the value

```
print(''+abc);
```

The output is

```
2517720935641121000
```

Is there any trick to print the value inside NumberLong?

Comment: `NumberLong` values are essentially "long integers" or 64-bit integers. There is no component to be "rounded down" as you claim. The response is likely a `Double` instead. You basically need to show what you are actually doing and sample data and result for a reasonable question that people can reproduce here as well. Edit your question please.

Comment: See my answer below, you need to quote your numbers when creating a `NumberLong` otherwise they are converted to floats first: NumberLong("2517720935641120769");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you quote the number when creating a `NumberLong` field. If you do not quote your value it will be cast to a float and you will loose precision.

```
NumberLong(123123123123131123).toString()
>>NumberLong("123123123123131120")
```

However, if you quote your value it will be correctly stored and returned:

```
NumberLong("123123123123131123").toString()
>>NumberLong("123123123123131123")
```

Both statements have been executed directly in the MongoShell, the value after `>>` gives the output returned by the MongoShell (version 3.0.7)

Comment: Thanks Jaco, it solves my problem. Apart from the quote for the number, the crucial information that I get is to use toString method instead of casting by adding empty string at the front of the NumberLong. Now I can get the string inside parentheses by using substring.

Comment: from the mongo shell, when print the json, it prints `NumberLong(3970813)` for instance ... i.e. without quotes. is there any way to recover the original value there? or do i need to parse the output of pringjson (becauase it is not valid json).

Answer (score 5):

Use the undocumented `exactValueString` property:

```
> NumberLong("2517720935641120769").exactValueString
2517720935641120769
```